# how can i set the value of Minimum (Maximum) Processor state

Tags: c#, windows-7, power-management

Under Win7, open Control Panel -> Power Options -> Advanced Settings->Processor power management.

you can see Minimum Processor state, Maximum Processor state.
I have get the value by powercfg command using C#.
Now,I want to set the value of Processor state by C#.
For example the old value is 5%,execute the programe,update the value to 10%.
I have search the powercfg help document,there are no such command to do this.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could only recommend calling [WriteProcessorPwrScheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373251.aspx) using PInvoke. [Windows API Code Pack for .NET](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) has some power management functions but probably not this one.

Comment: Thank you for your help,just you said,there are no functions for this.

Comment: @ScoketJoe I actually said there a function called WriteProcessorPwrScheme and you can certainly call it from C# using PInvoke. Have a look at the links.

Comment: oh,i have done it before,but the system metioned that requires 15 reputation,i am now 11.so i have no rights to do that.

Comment: Since the SO police are in effect on my actual answer.. there is a great .Net wrapper for those PInvoke calls: https://github.com/dahall/vanara

Answer (score 0):

use

```
PowerWriteACValueIndex()/PowerWriteDCValueIndex()
```

1st parameter is NULL, 2nd parameter -- GUID for desired power scheme (GUID_MAX_POWER_SAVINGS/GUID_MIN_POWER_SAVINGS/GUID_TYPICAL_POWER_SAVINGS), 3rd parameter -- GUID_PROCESSOR_SETTINGS_SUBGROUP, 4th parameter -- GUID_PROCESSOR_THROTTLE_MAXIMUM or GUID_PROCESSOR_THROTTLE_MINIMUM

all the GUID description could be found in winnt.h