# API for Minimum(Maximum) Processor State , C++

Tags: c++, processor, power-management

My question about the following available setting option in windows :
In windows and under Power option ==> advance power setting ==> Processor Power Management ==> Minimum Processor State ( Can be set as percentage%)

What is the corresponding API structure to this value, I would like to write a program which can control the % of the minimum and maximum processor state. I tried , SYSTEM_POWER_INFO, SYSTEM_POWER_CAPABILITY, .., nothing mentioned about this value specifically.

Pls advise.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is a Windows function called [WriteProcessorPwrScheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373251.aspx):

```
BOOLEAN WINAPI WriteProcessorPwrScheme(
  _In_  UINT ID,
  _In_  PMACHINE_PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY pMachineProcessorPowerPolicy
);
```

Source: I was tipped off by the C# answer in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617914/how-can-i-set-the-value-of-minimum-maximum-processor-state). Follow the docs to see all that goes into the `PMACHINE_PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY` structure.

According to the docs, though, that function does not affect the current system power policy. You need to call [SetActivePwrScheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373200.aspx):

```
BOOLEAN WINAPI SetActivePwrScheme(
  _In_      UINT uiID,
  _In_opt_  PGLOBAL_POWER_POLICY lpGlobalPowerPolicy,
  _In_opt_  PPOWER_POLICY lpPowerPolicy
);
```

If `SetActivePwrScheme` does not work or is not supported by your version of Windows, you can call [PowerSetActiveScheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372758.aspx):

```
DWORD WINAPI PowerSetActiveScheme(
  _In_opt_  HKEY UserRootPowerKey,
  _In_      const GUID *SchemeGuid
);
```

So it seems that you must first create a power scheme using `WriteProcessorPwrScheme`, which alters an index into a set of power schemes, and then you must call `SetActivePwrScheme` using that index to activate it.

Comment: Thanks AndyG, I am able to set the scheme, yet It will be useful if somebody can help me with direct function to adjust the % directly.

Comment: @Yasz: If you go deep enough into the `PPOWER_POLICY` structure, you finally come across `ForcedThrottleAc`:
The processor throttle level to be imposed by the system while the computer is running on AC (utility) power, expressed as a percentage. and 
`ForcedThrottleDc`:
The processor throttle level to be imposed by the system while the computer is running on battery power, expressed as a percentage.

Answer (score 2):

you can modify any power scheme using

```
PowerWriteACValueIndex()/PowerWriteDCValueIndex()
```

1st parameter is NULL,
2nd parameter -- GUID for desired power scheme (GUID_MAX_POWER_SAVINGS/GUID_MIN_POWER_SAVINGS/GUID_TYPICAL_POWER_SAVINGS),
3rd parameter -- GUID_PROCESSOR_SETTINGS_SUBGROUP,
4th parameter -- GUID_PROCESSOR_THROTTLE_MAXIMUM or GUID_PROCESSOR_THROTTLE_MINIMUM

all the GUID description could be found in winnt.h

Comment: Brilliant! Based on what you've posted, I've been able to write a complete program that changes the Minimum Processor State, then changes it back, by copying the current power scheme, editing the copy, making the copy active, then restoring the original scheme to being active. Code is here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/389633-how-to-control-cpus-speed-with-c-programming/page__view__findpost__p__2234351